# 'colorchooser' undeclared

Tags: xcode

Okay so I'm super brand new to cocoa and I have one failed thing. It says **'colorchooser' undeclared** on the first (colorchooser.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)I have no idea what's wrong!

```
//
//  Flashbox2ViewController.m
//  Flashbox2
//
//  Created by Paxton Harman on 2/1/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Santa Barbara City College. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Flashbox2ViewController.h"

@implementation Flashbox2ViewController
@synthesize colorChooser, sampleText;

-(IBAction) colorChanged {
    if (colorchooser.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) sampleText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    if (colorchooser.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) sampleText.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    if (colorchooser.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) sampleText.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: objective c , similar to c, is case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

choose colorchooser or colorChooser

Comment: specifically, you've defined/declared colorChooser, but you use colorchooser in your implementation of colorChanged.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I literally just started to learn this, so I knew it was something probably basic, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a @property of colorChooser and @synthesize it... then it is obvious that you should use colorChooser.selectedSegmentIndex and not colorchooser.selectedSegmentIndex...

Cheers